# Django Buildout to Virtualenv

Tags: django, heroku, virtualenv, buildout

beginner Django developer here.
I started a personale project with buildout and now I wanted to test some deploying, I decided to go with heroku, but I immediately noticed that heroku works with virtualenv and a requirements.txt file. My question is, is there a way to deploy a buildout project to heroku or convert said project to use virtualenv? If yes, how can I achieve this?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Buildout and virtualenv can work just fine together.

Upload your `buildout.cfg`, your `bootstrap.py` and use the virtualenv python to run the `bootstrap.py` script.

Kenneth Reitz (of `requests` fame, and Heroku's Python guy) has created a [buildpack](https://github.com/kennethreitz-archive/heroku-buildpack-buildout) that does just that.